# Process of equation solving never ends

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation, which seems to be pretty trivial to solve relatively to `u`, but despite that fact I can't make Mathematica to solve it:

```
eq = (Sqrt[2] Cp Sqrt[Sv] u^2 V \[CapitalTheta]mean \[Rho]^(
   3/2))/(\[Beta] (n1 \[CapitalLambda]1 + 
     n2 \[CapitalLambda]2) Sqrt[\[Sigma]1 + \[Sigma]2]) == (
  4 2^(15/16) Sqrt[3] Cv^(9/8) Sv^(11/16) u^(9/4) V^(9/8) \[Eta]^(
   1/8) \[Rho]^(7/16))/(
  g^(1/8) \[Pi]^(3/8) (3 Cv + 2 Cp \[Mu])^(
   9/8) (\[Sigma]1 + \[Sigma]2)^(9/16))
```

And my attempt to solve it leads to no error, but the solving process seems to never end.

```
Solve[eq, u, Reals]
```

[image]

As a workaround, I could manually simplify the equation, by raising the parts of equation to corresponding powers and etc. but it doesn't seem to me as a true way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This evaluates fast:

```
eq2 = p u^2 == q u^(9/4);
rules = {p -> (Sqrt[2] Cp Sqrt[Sv] V \[CapitalTheta]mean \[Rho]^(3/2))/(\[Beta]
          (n1 \[CapitalLambda]1 + n2 \[CapitalLambda]2) Sqrt[\[Sigma]1 + \[Sigma]2]), 
         q -> (4 2^(15/16) Sqrt[3] Cv^(9/8) Sv^(11/16) V^(9/8) \[Eta]^(1/8) \[Rho]^(7/16))/(
            g^(1/8) \[Pi]^(3/8) (3 Cv + 2 Cp \[Mu])^(9/8) (\[Sigma]1 + \[Sigma]2)^(9/16))};
eq === (eq2 /. rules)
```

> True

```
Solve[eq2, u, Reals] /. rules // FullSimplify
```

Always provide single symbol coefficients to the furthest possible extent in `Solve`